# The rift is healed!

Tags: discussion, announcement

At last Arduino is back together again.

- https://blog.arduino.cc/2016/10/01/two-arduinos-become-one-2/

The rift has been healed.  Massimo and Federico even hugged on stage (awww ;) )

We can now hope to get back to some form of normality - a single set of Arduino boards, just one Arduino IDE to wrestle with...

Comment: Good job! Great news!